# ¿Còmo hacer para que se guarde en una carpeta especifica?

Tags: c#

còmo puedo hacer que se guarde el archivo test1.txt en una carpeta especifica y no en la carpeta por defecto. Ya que estoy diciendo que se cree un archivo en `myEscrito = File.AppendText("test1.txt");`

```
private void btnInicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Start();
            lblestado.Text = "En Ejecución...";
            StreamWriter myEscrito = null;
            myEscrito = File.AppendText("test1.txt");
            string contenido = textBox1.Text;
            string contenido1 = textBox2.Text;
            string contenido2 = comboBox1.Text;
            string contenido3 = textBox3.Text;
            string contenido4 = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            myEscrito.WriteLine(contenido);
            myEscrito.WriteLine(contenido1);
            myEscrito.WriteLine(contenido2);
            myEscrito.WriteLine(contenido3);
            myEscrito.WriteLine(contenido4);

            myEscrito.Flush();
            myEscrito.Close();
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("se ha guardado con exito el evento");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo debes hacer así:

```
private void btnInicio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Esta es la dirección donde lo va a guardar.
    var path = "~/Directorio/";
 //lo combino con el nombre del archivo y la extensión
    path = Path.Combine(path, nombreArchivo + ".txt");

            timer.Start();
            lblestado.Text = "En Ejecución...";


            string contenido = textBox1.Text;
            string contenido1 = textBox2.Text;
            string contenido2 = comboBox1.Text;
            string contenido3 = textBox3.Text;
            string contenido4 = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
              file .WriteLine(contenido);
               file .WriteLine(contenido1);
              file .WriteLine(contenido2);
              file .WriteLine(contenido3);
              file .WriteLine(contenido4);

              file.Flush();
            }
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("se ha guardado con exito el evento");
        }
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Que pena, dònde puedo ubicar toda esa extenciòn? en el mismo private void?

Comment: @MY CHANNEL'SG Acabo de editar la respuesta agregando tu código, para que directamente lo puedas copiar. Solo recuerda reemplazar el directorio por el deseado y el nombre del archivo. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias. En la parte de "~/Directorio/" Serìa en mi caso "Documentos"  verdad?

Comment: En el using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true)) me marca error. ¿Por què serà?

Comment: Lo mas probable es que estes poniendo mal la path. Mostrame el error que te genera.